# .NET Regular Expression for N number of Consecutive Characters

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need a regular expression that matches three consecutive characters (any alphanumeric character) in a string.

> Where 2a82a9e4eee646448db00e3fccabd8c7
>   "eee" would be a match.
>
> Where
>   2a82a9e4efe64644448db00e3fccabd8c7
>   "444" would be a match.

etc.

Comment: @Chris: C# doesn't have regular expressions.

Comment: @John: really? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.aspx

Comment: For future reference, John's comment must be read in the context of the post date.

Comment: @robert: @chris: Those are .NET regular expressions, not C# regular expressions.

Comment: @John: Sheesh, John. You *know* what we mean. Is this your way of saying we're not being *precise enough?*

Comment: @Robert: I had addressed this to the OP. I find it useful to make the distinction between the language and the Framework. I should have used the longer form of the comment, "C# doesn't have _whatever_, .NET does".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use backreferences.

```
([a-zA-Z0-9])\1\1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {

    private static void DisplayMatches(string text,
                                       string regularExpressionString) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("using the following regular expression: " 
                        +regularExpressionString);
        MatchCollection myMatchCollection = 
            Regex.Matches(text, regularExpressionString);

        foreach (Match myMatch in myMatchCollection) {
          Console.WriteLine(myMatch);
        }
    }

    public static void Main() 
    {
        string text ="Missisipli Kerrisdale she";

        Console.WriteLine("Matching words that that contain " 
                          + "two consecutive identical characters");
        DisplayMatches(text, @"\S*(.)\1\S*");
    }
}
```